# how to delete row from join table with jpa 2

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql, join

i have a relationship one to many that generated a join table , what i need to do is to delete a row from that join table, but i dont even know how to do the jpql query to get to that table because it's not an entity in my data model.

to give an idea of my issue :

i have the next tables:

user--- (one to many)---> permission, that generated the table user_permission.

i need  to delete rows from user_permissions, because if i delete in permission all users with certain permission will lose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the permission from the list of permissions of the user and then save the user object. If the cascade is configured correctly that should delete the respective  entry from the join table.